# Wordpress A-Z Navigation

Tags: plugins

I want to have a wordpress "A-Z" navigation menu

like this site "http://www.sharephp.com/"

Are there any plugin or a hack for wordpress to do this ?

Comment: Rather than posting "we want to copy a feature off this site" why not list instead the specific features you're looking for?  There might not be a single "A-Z search plugin" out there, but someone might be able to help you merge 2-3 different systems or just post some custom code.

Answer (score 3):

Isnt it simpler and free from the need using plugin (always depending on the need for the author to update to the current wordpress version) to just use tags and just get all the tags (thus getting all the posts) of the letter "a" for example ?

Comment: That's a clever idea. Brainstorming... I'd go with a nonhierarchical taxonomy, and add a hook to save_post that programmatically assigns the post to the appropriate taxonomy based on the post's title.

Comment: That would make it even easier and more natural to use - great thinking :)

Comment: Nice ideas here. Maybe using a non-public custom taxonomy could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/azindex/

Only plugin I could find that does A-Z lists

Otherwise this is going to be a custom code job.

One hack way of doing this without much coding would be to make categories or tags for each letter, although I wouldn't recommend doing it this way.

Comment: I know that is an old post, I'm just wondering why wouldn't you recommend usage of categories or tags for creating A-Z list? Perhaps you change your mind after 7 years? :-)